Initial topology. Proof writing.
Let $X$ be a set. Let $(Y_i, \tau_i)$ be topological spaces and $f_i:X \to Y_i$ a family of mappings, $i \in I$. The set $X$ is endowed with the initial topology with respect to $\{f_i\}$. Let us consider the topological space $(Z, \tau_Z)$ and the mapping
$$ g: (Z, \tau_Z) \to (X, \tau).$$
Prove that $g$ is continuous if $f_i \circ g$ is continuous for all $i$.
I want to prove the result without using the notion of base or subbase for a topology. I am particularly interested in the writing aspect of the proof.
My attempt
We have to show that
$$ g^{-1}(G) \in \tau_Z, \ \forall G \in \tau.$$
We observe that
$$ \tau = \{ \text{arbitrary unions of } \bigcap_{i \in J} f_i^{-1}(U_i) \}, $$
where $J \subset I$ finite and $U_i \in \tau_i$. It suffices now to see that $g^{-1}$ preserves finite intersections and arbitrary unions and use $ g^{-1} \circ f_i^{-1} = (f_i \circ g)^{-1}.$ We conclude by using that a finite intersection of open sets is an open set and an arbitrary union of open sets is an open set.
Is this proof valid in this case? What would the proof be if we want to use math notation? Is the notion of subbase or base required? Thanks.

Indeed, there is a much simpler way to prove this result without the notion of base or subbase for a topology.
Let´s define a new topology $\tau'$ in $X$ as follows:
$$G \in \tau' \ \text{ if } \ g^{-1}(G) \in \tau_{Z}.$$
It suffices then to see that $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$, that is, every open set of $\tau$ is an open set of $\tau'$. As $\tau$ is built from
$$ f_i^{-1}(U_i),  \ U_i \in \tau_i, \ i \in I,$$
let´s simply check that $f_i^{-1}(U_i) \in \tau', \ \forall i \in  I:$
$$ g^{-1}(f_i^{-1}(U_i)) = (f_i \circ g)^{-1}(U_i) \in \tau_{Z},$$
where we used that $\forall i \in I, \ f_i \circ g \ $ is continuous.
